# sprockets - precompiling a standalone asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets, digest, pre-compilation

I am trying to make sprokets compile a single standalone js asset, so it will uglify and minify it and be part of the entire rails projects.

I need that this js to have a non-digest name, so it's will not change (i.e. embedded in other websites, etc)

I can't seem to force rails (4) /sprockets to do my bidding.

What I tried:

1. Adding the asset (`script.js`) in a misc folder unders assets/javascripts and not load it in the sprockets javascript manifest. While this keeps it in the project, it doesn't get uglified and minified, and doesn't get automatically loaded via asset-sync.
2. Tried adding another manifest called `scripts-manifest.js` to `//= require script.js` asset, to add its path in the precompile path in `application.rb`, but the problem is that rails 4 adds digest to all assets no matter what (doesn't work like that in rails 3)
3. Tried using https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets to add a non digest version of the asset. I may have done it incorrectly, as it doesn't work or do anything..

   I add the initializer `NonStupidDigestAssets.whitelist = ["script.js"]` and tried putting it in app/assets/javascripts/misc and in public/ but it still won't work/

I have read that this gem should help in most cases, and I am sure I am doing something wrong with either path definition or no including it somewhere

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to add an initializer that generates the compiled versions directly.

1. Add your js file to a subfolder in `/app/assets/javascripts`. Don't include this in `application.js` so it isn't added to the compiled assets.
2. Create an initializer in `/config/initializers` that uses uglify directly

   `output_file = "#{Rails.root}/public/public_script.js"`

   `input_file = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/javascripts/non_digest/public_script.js"`

   `uglified = Uglifier.compile(File.read(input_file))`

   `File.open(output_file, 'w') {|f| f.write(uglified) }`
3. Include the public js file (in this example: `/public/public_script.js`) in your application layout

This way you have direct access to make custom changes to how [uglify](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier#usage) handles your js and the location of the file never changes for your external services accessing them.

I did all this locally and tested that it worked using the beta version of Rails 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add my own solution based off Ken's answer.

I created `non_digest.rb` in `config/initializers`:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/assets/javascripts/non_digest/*"].each do |asset|
  asset_name = File.basename(asset)
  asset_output = "#{Rails.root}/public/external/#{asset_name}"
  asset_uglified = Uglifier.compile(File.read(asset))

  File.open(asset_output, 'w') {|a| a.write(asset_uglified) }
end
```

Don't forget to stub the file in `javascripts/application.js`. as we probably don't want it compiled with the rest of our JS and we can continue to use `//= require_tree .`:

`//= stub non_digest/external_bookmarklet`

Comment: i use this in my rails console to test my assets to avoid real time surprises on the production server during deployment

Answer (score 0):

the way you would do this with rails 4 is the following:

- add it to the precompile list `config.assets.precompile += %w(your_file_name.js)`
- make sure it's not referenced in `application.js` (directly or via `require_tree`)
- symlink the digested file on deployment

  - read the `manifest.yml` to get the actual filename
  - `ln -s digested-filename.js actual-filename.js`

since rails 4, generation of non-digested assets has been removed (for good reasons) and this is a simple and straight forward way to implement the desired behavior.

Comment: is there a way to do it without symlinking? Since I am deploying in heroku

Comment: i think this pretty much sums it up: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49#issuecomment-26020304